# How to program a fake stm32f103c6?

Tags: stm32

I bought a blue pill that I tried to program using STLink on CubeMX IDE.

I got this:

> Warn : UNEXPECTED idcode: 0x2ba01477
>       Error: expected 1 of 1: 0x1ba01477

I checked on the internet and I found that it's a fake one.  I got the idea to edit the
stm32f1.cfg file so I changed

> set _CPUTAPID 0x2ba01477

to

> set _CPUTAPID 0x1ba01477

It worked perfectly the first time, but after a couple of seconds the green LED turned on and now the problem I have is:

> Error: init mode failed (unable to connect to the target)

Any help please? I can't afford another blue pill for the moment and I really need it for my studies.

Answer (score 6):

Possibly, you have loaded a program that uses the SWD pins for other purposes than connecting a debugger or that otherwise negatively affects the SWD pins.

Set the BOOT0 jumper to 1 and restart the BluePill. That way, it starts in bootloader mode instead of starting your program. That way, you should be able to connect the STLink again and uplad a new program. After the upload, set the jumper back to 0.

**Update**

BTW. A BluePill usually has a STM32F103C**8** chip (or clone), not a STM32F103C**6**. The difference is 64K vs 32K of flash. Make sure you have selected to correct chip.

Comment: thank you verry much it's working but there's something i din't understand every time i wanna program the stm32 i need to go to the bootloader mode even if i put an empty program i can't program it when the jumper is on 0  and yes it's c8 not c6 sorry

Comment: That's strange. Do you have the STLink connected to the SWCLK and SWDIO pins on the short side of the board? And if you use STM32CubeMX to generate the code, you might need to set System Core / SYS / Mode / Debug to *Serial Wire*.

Answer (score 1):

This post is the perfect answer for my fake STM32F1.

The steps I followed

1. Debug config set to OPENOCD , Boot1 Jumper = 0
2. The id has to be changed to 0x1ba01477 in stm32f1 cfg file
3. set System Core / SYS / Mode / Debug to Serial Wire in CUBE ide( thanks to @code)
4. Before starting debug do the following
   a. Set Reset mode to "Software system reset"
   b. Set Low power debug
   c. Set stop wdg on halt
5. Press and hold reset in Board ( for the first time to flash this firmware with JTAG enabled in software )
6. Press debug button on IDE
7. Look for the debug message in console window and release the RESET during init to connect.

After doing this once , debug mode works normally.

Answer (score 1):

1. Debug config set to OPENOCD , Boot1 Jumper = 0
2. Change code command
   #jtag scan chain
   set _CPUTAPID 0x1ba01477 in stm32f1x.cfg file
3. Set System Core / SYS / Mode / Debug to Serial Wire in <your_file>.ioc
4. Before starting debug do the following (in Debug Configurations)

   1. Set Reset mode to "Software system reset"
   2. Set Low power debug
   3. Set stop wdg on halt
   4. In connection setup choose suitable frequency value if console has error relate to Mhz
   5. In Startup enter command: monitor flash mass_erase
5. Now you don't need hold the reset button to debug and download your code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much less invasive method to change the CPUTAPID from the `platformio.ini`. You just need to add it as `upload_flags`. Here is an example `platformio.ini`:

```
[env:bluepill_f103c8]

platform=ststm32
board=bluepill_f103c8
framework=libopencm3
upload_protocol=stlink
upload_flags=
    -c
    set CPUTAPID 0x2ba01477
```